# How to fix the problem of power button stuck a bit inside and not working?

Tags: buttons

I accidentally dropped a cell phone (Honor 8) over and over again, and now the power button (the small one on the right side, below the volume button) seems to be pushed inside a bit and stuck there. It now stops working no  matter how hard I push it. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How to fix the power button: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea_hhtT5rNU Or just go to a repair shop.