# Honor 8 : Is there a way of taking a screenshot without using the power button?

Tags: android-11, buttons, accessibility, screenshots

When I used to take a screenshot on a cell phone (Honor 8, not rooted, Android 8.0.0), I push the power button and the volume button together. But now the power button on a cell phone has stopped working (see [How to fix the problem of power button stuck a bit inside and not working?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253364/how-to-fix-the-problem-of-power-button-stuck-a-bit-inside-and-not-working)). Is there a way of taking a screenshot without using the power button? Is there something similar to accessibility tools on an operating system (such as virtual keyboard in Ubuntu)? Thanks.

Comment: @beeshyams thanks. It's Honor 8. It is not rooted. Google and a large part of the Internet is censored and inaccessible here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that internet is [censored](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253365/honor-8-is-there-a-way-of-taking-a-screenshot-without-using-the-power-button/253373#comment343553_253365) in your country, here are two links, that describe how to take a screen shot without a <kbd>power</kbd> button.

1. [Youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dbzw-kAiT9NE&ved=2ahUKEwikwvyFvc-BAxX_cmwGHcQ6CP8QFnoECAwQBA&usg=AOvVaw0uIW-6T6zrSHgOJyG3Ngxj), specifically for Honor 8
2. [How to take a screenshot on HONOR smartphones?](https://www.hihonor.com/global/club/topicdetail/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-honor-smartphones/topicid-68676/) for Honor phones in general (from Honor forums).

a) **Notification Bar Shortcut:** HONOR makes it more intuitive to take a screenshot by giving you a shortcut in the notification area.(or quick setting tiles) It looks like scissors cutting paper. Select it to get your screenshot. GIF from the website.

[image]

b) **Knock on the screen with your knuckle:** Certain HONOR phones have a very fun and interactive way to take a screenshot. You can simply knock on your screen twice using your knuckle! This feature needs to be activated first, though. Just go to Settings → Accessibility features  Shortcuts & gestures → Take screenshot → Enable Knuckle screenshots. GIF from the website

[image]

**Both these methods are mentioned in the YouTube video for Honor 8 as well**

c) **Three-Finger Screenshot:** By using Three-finger screenshot, you can easily capture a screenshot on your Phone. Open Settings. Go to Accessibility features & → Shortcuts &Gestures → Take Screenshot , and Enable Three-finger screenshot. You can then swipe down on the screen with three fingers to capture a screenshot (some One Plus phones have this as I recall from OP7 I owned previously)

Hoping one of these works for you or someone else in a similar situation (also see [How to take a screenshot with an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1759/131553) for other methods of taking screenshots)